# Finding two constants in a cumulative distribution function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have been trying to do this problem for the last hour and cannot find anything on how to find two constants in a CDF. The Problem is:

> A random variable X has cumulative distribution function F(x) = A/x + B for 1 <= x <= 4. Find A and B.

I am seriously at a loss and this is only the first problem. Please help.

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  A cumulative distribution function is zero at the low end of the random variable's range, and one at the top end.  Those two conditions should help determine parameters $A,B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a homework problem?

By definition of the CDF, $F(1)=0$ and $F(4)=1$. From the first condition, $A+B=0$ so $B=-A$ and from the second condition $A/4+B=1$ so $-3A/4 = 1$ and thus $A=-4/3$. Hence
$$
F(x)=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{4/3}{x}.
$$

Comment: "Is this a homework problem?" It very much looks like one... and this puts your decision to provide a complete, detailed, explicit, answer in a peculiar light, don't you think?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning, how so?

Comment: "How so" what? Please explain what you are not following in the crystal clear point I made.

Comment: Two days later... it seems that explaining what was not clear in my first comment is not something the OP is willing / able to achieve. In this context, the likeliest interpretation of the OP's reaction is that it was in fact a deliberate evasion of the problem raised by my comment. Good to know.